# Stenciljs: Carousel third-party library destroyed when I change scope: 'true' for shadow: 'true'

Tags: stenciljs, swiper.js

I've a carousel based on the Swiperjs third-party library. The problem is that when I use scope: true, I have no problem and it works fine, however, when I try to configure the component with shadow: true, it is destroyed and nothing works. I am using the library as follows:

```js
...
import  Swiper, { SwiperOptions }  from 'swiper';
...

@Component({
  tag: 'my-swiper-slider',
  styleUrl: './styles.css',
  assetsDirs: ['assets'],
  shadow: true,
})
export class Carousel {
@Prop() options: SwiperOptions = {
    slidesPerView: 3,
    spaceBetween: 40,
    autoplay: false,
    loop: false,
    autoHeight: true,
    breakpoints: {
      640: {
        slidesPerView: 5,
        spaceBetween: 20,
      },
      768: {
        slidesPerView: 5,
        spaceBetween: 40,
      },
      1024: {
        slidesPerView: 5,
        spaceBetween: 50,
      },
    }
  }
 private setSwiper() {
    this.swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', this.options);
  }

  componentDidLoad() {
    this.setSwiper();
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <Host class={{"container": true}}>

        <PrevBtn
          goBack={this.goBack.bind(this)} />

        <div class="swiper-container">
          <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <slot></slot>
          </div>
        </div>

        <NextBtn
          goForward={this.goForward.bind(this)} />

      </Host>
    );
  }
}
```

For some reason, when I configure the component as "shadow: true", it cannot access stencil or is what I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you enable `shadow`, all child elements of the component will be moved into its shadow DOM and therefore be hidden as implementation detail. That means that you won't be able to find your container with the `.swiper-container` query selector anymore.

However, the `Swiper` constructor can also take an HTML element instead of a query selector, so you can use `ref` on the container element instead:

```
@Component({ tag: 'my-swiper-slider', shadow: true })
export class Carousel {
  @Prop() options: SwiperOptions;

  @State() swiper?: Swiper;
  @State() swiperContainerRef?: HTMLDivElement;

  componentDidLoad() {
    if (this.swiperContainerRef) {
      this.swiper = new Swiper(this.swiperContainerRef, this.options);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Host>
        <div ref={el => this.swiperContainerRef = el)} />
      </Host>
    );
  }
}
```

The container ref should always already be available in the `componentDidLoad` life-cycle hook, but you can also use [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) to wait for it to become available.

Comment: Hello Simon, thank you for your answer. I get the next warning message and doesn't works: "The state/prop "swiper" changed during "componentDidLoad()", this triggers extra re-renders, try to setup on "componentWillLoad()" " But when I change the life-cycle hook, I get an error: "Cannot read property '$hostElement$' of undefined"

Comment: Yes, the reference is only available after the initial render (when the DOM element has been created). That's why a re-render is actually required in this case. So you can safely ignore the warning.